# Unable to set time HH:mm:ss in amchart?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, amcharts

I am using amcharts and i am unable to set hours/minute in chart. It is always showing 00:00.

```
// Set date label formatting
    dateAxis.dateFormats.setKey("day", "yyyy/MMM/dd HH:mm");
```

I am passing milliseconds

```
let newDate = new Date(parseInt(this.vitalHistoryEachData[i]['observation-time']));
```

[image]

I am pushing data in list

```
chartData.push({
date:newDate,
DataSet1: DataSet1,
DataSet2: DataSet2
});
```

I have created a sample at https://codesandbox.io/s/4mzp27v67

Comment: can you create the stackblitz for this

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/4mzp27v67

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are specifying "day".

You need to set your date granularity.

> **Data granularity** A date/time-based data can come at different intervals. For example, we could have just one entry per year, or we
>   can have a data point every millisecond.
>
> Date axis will do turn on its wits to determine the granularity by
>   examining your actual data. So, if you have data points with a minute
>   between them, the axis will determine the best granularity to use is a
>   minute.
>
> Data granularity affects how axis grid is drawn, and how labels are
>   formatted. E.g. if you have a data point each day, it makes sense to
>   display a grid line and a date label for each data point.

Look here: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/#Data_granularity

Comment: I have used this code "dateAxis.dateFormats.setKey("date", "yyyy/MMM/dd HH:mm");" and it is not working.

Comment: Do you have a sample up on Codepen or similar?